# Scala implicit for Option containing Map

Tags: scala, implicit

I am trying to write the following implicit:

```
implicit class ExtractOrElse[K, V](o: Option[Map[K, V]]) {
  def extractOrElse(key: K)(f: => V): V = { if (o.isDefined) o.get(key) else f }
}
```

Which I want to use in this way:

```
normalizationContexts.extractOrElse(shardId)(defaultNormalizationContext)
```

to avoid a clunkier syntax (`normalizationContexts` is an `Option[Map[String, NormzalitionContext]]`).

Also, let me add that it is intentional that there is only one default value: it will be used if the `Option` `isEmpty`, but if the `Option` `isDefined`, then the behavior of the `Map` is not changed, and it will throw an exception if the key is not found - so the default value won't be used in that case, and this is all intentional.

However, I get an error when passing in `None` in unit tests:

```
assertEquals(None.extractOrElse('a')(0), 0)
```

results in:

```
Error:(165, 37) type mismatch;
 found   : Char('a')
 required: K
  assertEquals(None.extractOrElse('a')(0), 0)
```

I realize that `None` is not parametric, as it is defined as:

```
case object None extends Option[Nothing] {
  def isEmpty = true
  def get = throw new NoSuchElementException("None.get")
```

What is the best way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `None.extractOrElse(...)`, try `Option.empty[Map[Char, Int]].extractOrElse(...)`.

If you always use the same types for your test cases, you could also create a type alias in the specs class in order to reduce the clutter:

```
type OpMap = Option[Map[Char, Int]]
// ...
assertEquals(Option.empty[OpMap].extractOrElse('a')(0), 0)
```

Just in case, you can use `flatMap` and `getOrElse` to achieve the same thing without writing a new method:

```
val n = Option.empty[Map[String, Int]]
val s = Some(Map("x" → 1, "y" → 2))

n.flatMap(_.get("x")).getOrElse(3)  // 3
s.flatMap(_.get("x")).getOrElse(3)  // 1
s.flatMap(_.get("z")).getOrElse(3)  // 3
```

Comment: Interesting - I could use `flatMap.getOrElse` in the implementation of `extractOrElse` (I still like the simpler syntax).

Comment: Is it `Option.empy[OpMap]` or `Option.empty[Map[String, Int]]`? I think it is the latter ...

Comment: Also, is it `flatMap` or `map`? `flatMap`'s signature is `flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B]`.

Comment: @Frank: for my example it's `[Map[String, Int]]`, but for yours it's `[OpMap]`.

Comment: @Frank: if you use `map` you get nested `Option`s, so you'd need to `getOrElse` at two levels: `m.map(_.get("x").getOrElse(3)).getOrElse(3)`. By using `flatMap` you flatten the nested `Option`s, being able to `getOrElse` only once.

Answer (score 1):

The type system doesn't have enough information about the types `K` and `V`.  There is no way to know what the type of `A` would be in the case where your `None` was `Some[A]`.

When I create an example with explicit types, the code works as expected:

```
// Like this
val e = new ExtractOrElse(Option.empty[Map[Char, Int]])
e.extractOrElse('a')(0) // Equals 0

// Or like this
val e = new ExtractOrElse[Char, Int](None)
println(e.extractOrElse('a')(0))

// Or like this
val m: Option[Map[Char, Int]] = None
val e = new ExtractOrElse(m)
println(e.extractOrElse('a')(0))
```

Comment: The last two examples can be written better as `println((None: Option[Map[Char, Int]]).extractOrElse('a')(0)`. This is the simplest answer to the problem.

Comment: I figured three different examples illustrating how to provide type information was sufficient.